# Cannot access IIS manager on my server 2019 through windows 10

Tags: iis, windows-10, windows-server-2019

I created a VM server 2019 and I don't want my employees to have remote access to the server. But I want them to be able to access the IIS on the server through a windows 10 machine. I went to the IIS manager in the server and added the users to the IIS manager permission through active directory. On my windows 10, I went to control panel-Programs-Turn Windows Feature on or off and enabled the IIS. So what's happening is that they can find the IIS Manager app under the start menu on windows 10, but when they try to open it there's a pop-up asking if want to allow changes to the device, then it asks for their passwords. And after they enter the password a new pop-up comes up saying I need to be an Administrator to use IIS manager. They are not admin to windows 10 and I don't want for them to be admin. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: "On my windows 10, I went to control panel-Programs-Turn Windows Feature on or off and enabled the IIS. So what's happening is that they can find the IIS Manager app under the start menu on windows 10" is wrong. Windows 10 users must install this special version of IIS Manager https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to delegate IIS administration to non-admin user.

Then you need to install IIS manager for remote administration 1.2 as lex said. Once you install it, IIS will no longer as for administrator prevelige.

[image]

The next you need to do is install IIS management and create IIS manager user. Then you could add your win10's IP to management service IP restirction, so only your win 10 have permission to connect the server.

PS:Please remember to allow 8172 in windows firewall.
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/leesab/delegating-iis-administration-to-domain-users-non-administrators

Comment: I need for them to authenticate through the credentials in Active Directory

Comment: @ANA If so, you could use Winodws-credential only and grant permission in IIS manger->site node->IIS manager permission

Answer (score 3):

Remote administration 1.2 no longer available for download.

Make sure the WinRM IIS Extension is checked and installed on Win Server 2019 (Under "Feature" selection. (Add Roles and Features Wizard)
This is the missing piece that took me an hour to figure out in the latest version.